# Bootstrap Navbar buttons get stacked in mobile

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I have added buttons to my Bootstrap navbar like this:

```
<!-- Image and text -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.seekadventure.net">
    <img src="myLogo.png" width="155.66" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
  </a>

  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <li class="nav-item" style="padding-right:25px ">
      <button  class="btn btn-warning" onclick="locateMe()">
        <i class="fas fa-street-view"> </i>
      </button>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        <i class="fas fa-filter"></i>
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

It looks great on desktop (Except for colors but I will fix that later) but on mobile, they get stacked and not even stacked directly on top of each other. Not sure why it's getting auto moved to the top like this:

[image]

How can I force the two icons to stay next to each other? There should be plenty of real estate for the buttons not have to stack in mobile.

Comment: Is that a `float-right` I spy in your second button's classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add "flex-row align-items-center" in ul class and removed "float-right" from the last button class. These are predefined classes of bootstrap 4 so no need to write extra CSS for this. This will show same results as your desktop view.

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-row align-items-center">
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="locateMe()">
        <i class="fas fa-street-view"> </i>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        <i class="fas fa-filter"></i>
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Curious why flex-row align-items-center moves them to the right edge though? That line makes me think it would align it center.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using float on your buttons like that, instead, try to stay consistent, and use inline display on those too. Regardless though, I don't know how your styles are laid out, so the easiest solution I've found for your problem without changing any other classes is to simply add this to your css:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

This will force your elements to stay layed out horizontally, even though on smaller resolutions Bootstrap assumes you no longer want to keep them in one line.